# Macbook battery runs flat while "charging" with nearly full USB Brick

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, battery, charging, power

Road warriors buy Macbooks for untethered working and at times find themselves in a place without a powerpoint.  So charging a Macbook from a USB Brick is a fundamental operational requirement.  I thought I'd just plug my **2018 Macbook Pro** into a USB Power Brick and it would just "work".  *How wrong I was*...

***The USB Brick charged at such a poor rate my Macbook's battery would run flat despite having almost a full 26800 mAH Brick connected to it via the USB-C/Thunderbolt port to charge it.*** Something was badly wrong.  ***Was it the USB brick I was using?  Was it the cable?  Was it a combination of these things?***  Much head scratching...

Since this is an issue I feel of broad interest for all mobile workers, I'll give a thorough treatment of the issue and how I resolved it in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

### SHORT ANSWER:

The **non-** Apple cable I was using with the Anker USB brick **WAS** killing charging performance as proven by the testing I did which is documented in the "***Long Answer***" section which follows

The Apple USB-C/Thunderbolt cable would require a *USB2.0-to-USB-C* adapter to work with my Anker USB brick, so I just bought a brick with native USB-C support which works great:

[Zendure X6 45W 5 Ports USB-C Hub Portable Charger 20000mAh PD&QC 3.0 Power Bank](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B075Q5YTFJ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

**HOWEVER:** I remarked in the comments in the Apple store that the Apple USB-C/Thunderbolt cable received many 1-star reviews; not robust. Coiling & uncoiling this cable seemed likly to damage it, so I did some searching on Amazon and found the following cable, which works well with the ***Zandure X6*** Brick from my (short) experience of it:

[Anker USB-C to USB-C Thunderbolt 3.0 Fast Charging and Data Transfer Cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B076D76DRQ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Now my brick runs flat first before the Macbook's battery begins to run-down.  Problem solved.

Do remember to shut-down any unnecessary CPU-intensive tasks while running on a USB brick or you will watch it drain fast. And I do mean "**FAST**"

If you want to see how I arrived at my results, please continue reading "*Long Answer*" section.  Lots of pictures to support my analysis

### LONG ANSWER

Since my Macbook charged correctly using the supplied 87 Watt Power Adapter and USB-C/Thunderbolt cable, I needed to assess the charging properties of this connection to obtain a baseline of what "*normal*" performance was.  ***But how?***

### Task #1: Identify Appropriate Power Meter:

I'm not an electrical engineer, but searching in Amazon I found the tool for the job:

[Jokitech USB Type C PowerMeter tester](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B073Z62GRF/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

### Task 2: Identify baseline performance of a correct power connection

Armed with the *Jokitech* tool, I measured the properties of the stock Apple 87 Watt Power Adapter and USB-C cable that ships with my ***Macbook Pro 2018***:

**Stock Apple 87 Watt Power Adapter using Apple USB-C Thundebolt Charging cable**
[image: Stock Apple 87 Watt Power Adapter using Apple USB-C Thundebolt Charging cable]

The voltage fluctuated between **19.7**-**19.9** volts, so we'll use the median number **19.8** as a baseline for assessing performance of other USB cables.

### Task #3: Determine charging performance using a USB Brick with non-Apple cable

This test I swapped-out the Apple 87 Watt Power Adapter with an Anker USB brick to power my Macbook

**Anker 26800 mAH USB Power Brick and USB 2.0-to-USB-C cable**
[image: Anker 26800 mAH USB Power Brick and USB 2.0-to-USB-C cable]

***The voltage of the USB Brick's cable is barely 1/4*** of the correctly charging connection using stock Apple Power Adapter & USB-C/Thunderbolt cable.

***But is it the USB Brick or the Cable- or both?!?!***

### Task #4: Compare Apple USB-C cable with non-Apple cable

The Anker Brick I had been using had no **USB-C** interface, so I found the [Zendure X6 45W (5) Port USB-C Hub Portable Charger 20000mAh PD&QC 3.0 Power Bank](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B075Q5YTFJ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) which enabled me to test both the non-Apple cable reporting low voltage and the Apple USB-C/Thunderbolt cable with the same USB brick.

The first test shown below with the non-Apple cable reporting low-voltage, ***still demonstrates same poor 5-ish volts performance*** with the new brick when connected to the USB-C port via an adapter:

[image: Anker 26800 mAH with USB 2.0-to-USB-C Cable with USB-C adapter]

Now, if I connect the Apple USB-C Cable which was known to work correctly with the Power Adapter and it continues to operate at about 19.8v (or thereabouts), then that cable I was using with the Anker was causing me the pain.  Let's see how tha Apple USB-C cable behaves:

[image: Apple USB-C/Thunderbolt cable used with Brick]

Note that there's no issues with low voltage with the Apple cable.  The original cable I had tried with both the Anker & Zandure X6 USB bricks performed 5-ish volts consistently. As you can see, the USB cable you use to charge from a USB brick can have a **HUGE** effect on charging performance

Comment: Devices need to negotiate to get more than "old"-USB power.  Apparently that is not possible if you do not use modern devices and cables.

Comment: That USB-A to USB-C cable (you refer it to as the "non-Apple" cable) is for charging *phones* that accept 5V and up to 2.5A.  That's why you're seeing that low value.  The MacBook and it's charger conform the [USB 3.1 Power Delivery specification](https://www.usb.org/usb-charger-pd) which *negotiate* the wattage delivered.  This is like using Mini to tow a caravan instead of a pickup or van (people carrier) wondering why it never got above 10 mph - you selected the wrong thing for the load you're trying to pull

Comment: I bought the cable because it had one end that fit my Macbook and another end that fit the USB brick ;-).  Don't believe there was any level of detail such as you (very usefully) provided, so I just clicked "buy".  I figure since only recently bricks are now shipping with native USB-C connectivity, others will likely make the error I did when sourcing a cable that works with their (legacy) USB brick.  Just trying to save them the grief of working out how it was going wrong.  Much obliged for your useful feedback @Allan